# cannot read property $store of undefined in nuxt conditions

Tags: nuxt.js

I have encountered an error during a conditonal formatting in Nuxt

```
<SidebarNavLink  v-if="this.$store.state.authUser.roles.includes(childL1.keyword) || this.$store.state.authUser.roles.includes('super') || this.$store.state.authUser.roles.includes('admin')" :name="childL1.name" :url="childL1.url" :icon="childL1.icon" :badge="childL1.badge" :variant="item.variant"/>
```

Comment: what error...??

Comment: @Aldarund cannot read property $store of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont reference this in template. Only is js. Change your code from `v-if="this.$store` to `v-if="$store` and it will do the trick